# Sharing Sessions with 302 Redirects/IMG SRC/ JSON-P and implications with Google SEO/Pagerank or Other Problems

Tags: php, javascript, apache, session

I am currently researching the best way to share the same session across two domains (for a shared shopping cart / shared account feature).  I have decided on two of three different approaches:

Every 15 minutes, send a one time only token (made from a secret and user IP/user agent) to "sync the sessions" using:

1. img src tag

   img src="http://domain-two.com/sessionSync.png?token="urlsafebase64_hash"

   - displays an empty 1x1 pixel image and starts a remote session session with the same session ID on the remote server.  The png is actually a PHP script with some mod_rewrite action.
   - Drawbacks:  what if images are disabled?
2. a succession of 302 redirect headers (almost same as above, just sending token using 302's instead:

   - redirect to domain-2.com/sessionSync.php?token="urlsafebase64_hash"
   - then from domain-2.com/sessionSync, set(or refresh) the session and redirect back to domain-1.com to continue original request.
   - QuestionL What does Google think about this in terms of SEO/Pagerank??  Will their bots have issues crawling my site properly?  Will they think I am trying to trick the user?
   - Drawbacks:  3 requests before a user gets a page load, which is slower than the IMG technique.
   - Advantages: Almost always works?
3. use jsonp  to do the same as above.

   - Drawbacks: won't work if javascript is disabled.  I am avoiding this option because of particularly this.
   - Advantages:  callback function on success may be useful (but not really in this situation)

My questions are:

- What will google think of using 302's as stated in example 2 above?  Will they punish me?
- What do you think the best way is?
- Are there any security considerations introduced by any of these methods?
- Am I not realizing something else that might cause problems?

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: I prepared a paper on this, going into quite a bit of detail.  I'll post it here as an answer when I have time, or contact me for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:
You could use the **jsonP** approach and use the `<noscript>` tag to set the 302-chains mode.

You won't find a lot of js disabled clients in the human part of your web clients.

But the web crawlers will mostly fall in the 302-chain mode, and if you care about them you could maybe implement some user-agent checks in sessionSync to give them specific instructions. For example give them a 301 permanent redirect. Your session synchronistation needs are maybe not valid for web crawlers, maybe you can redirect them permanently (so only the first time) without handling any specific session synchronisation for them. Well it depends ofg your implementation of this 302-chains but you could as well set something in the crawlers session to let them crawl domain-1 without any check on domain-2, as this depends on the url you generate on the page, and that you could have something in the session to prevent the domain-2 redirect  on url generation.

Comment: Thanks regilero for answering.  Wont work with <noscript> because that happens after headers are sent, and doing 302 redirects are done in headers.

Comment: I've read some posts by matt cutts that talk about 302 chains and how browsers handle them.  Back in the day, it was an issue, these days its not as much thanks to heuristics.

301 redirects are not what we want to do at all, because that will tell the search engine that we want to use Page B instead, which is not the case.

I ended up going away from using 302 redirects to pass the session info and am using a combo of an img tag and a iframe with a form post instead.  It is a quite a bit quicker due to the page requests being at the end of the page load instead.